# display videos of different formats in html page

Tags: html, video, mp4, flv

I have different formats of videos on my hard disk, i want to display then in a html page,
for example as of now i had `.mp4` and `.flv` video formats = and trying to display with the below html code

```
<div style="padding-top:90px;">
  <video id="vid" width="350" height="250" controls="controls">
           <source src="/home/user/videos/django_cms_1280x720.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   </video>
  <video id="vid_re" width="350" height="250" controls="controls">
           <source src="/home/user/videos/1100000.flv" type="video/mp4" />       
   </video>
</div>
```

So when the html page is rendered/opened in the browser, `django_cms_1280x720.mp4` video is playing with no problem, but the `1100000.flv` is not playing.......

Can anyone please let me know how to display and play the videos of different format on html page ?

**Edited**

Since `.flv` videos are not supported by the html, i have converted them to mp4 and edited the code as below and still i am unable to play the video, the page just displaying the blank image of video

```
  <video id="vid_re" width="350" height="250" controls="controls">
           <source src="/home/user/videos/1100000_cnvtd.mp4" type="video/mp4" />       
   </video>
```

Comment: Are you certain that 1100000.flv is a MP4 file? The extension is .flv, and that won't be supported by any HTML5-compatible browser (it's a Flash Video format).

Comment: i had edited my question,can you please have a look at it ?

Comment: The next troubleshooting step is to make sure that 1100000_cnvtd.mp4 is okay. Does it play in any other media player that you happen to have? Since you have 'ffmpeg' installed, you should have 'ffprobe' as well. Run ffprobe against 1100000_cnvtd.mp4. Is it H.264 video and AAC audio?

Comment: after converting to mp4, i tried to open that video by clicking on it, and its playing well !!!!

Comment: That answers the first question, but how about the second: What codecs are inside? General media players are a lot more accepting that HTML5-compatible web browsers.

Comment: the command i have used is ffmpeg -i /home/user/videos/1100000.mp4 /home/user/videos/1100000_cnvtd.mp4

Comment: And i am really sorry i dont know the concept of codecs, can u please provide me the full command of converting the vide to mp4 using codecs ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25763/discussion-between-shiva-krishna-and-multimedia-mike)

Answer (score 0):

FLV is not supported as a native format to be played by browsers. You'll have to use a plug-in to play flv on your website.

You can try:

```
http://flowplayer.org/
```

Comment: k i had converted the flv file in to mp4 file by ffmeg command in linux and tried to display the same, but it doesn't worked , the image blank of video is displaying on the screen, but it in unplayable format, i mean the video is not playing ?

Comment: you might not have converted it with the right settings. If the other mp4 file is playing, there is clearly no problem with the browser.

Comment: the command i have used is ffmpeg -i  /home/user/videos/1100000.mp4    /home/user/videos/1100000_cnvtd.mp4

Comment: I am sorry, but i don't have much experience with ffmpeg. why don't you rather use a free GUI program to convert the video. try http://winff.org/html_new/

Comment: Here all my intention and concept is, i will have a webpage that will uploads the videos to disk, so the user can upload any kind of video formats, i want to convert them to the format that is supported by html, because we are displaying all the uploaded videos directly in the html page using video tag

Comment: Your ffmpeg command line looks wrong. By default, asking FFmpeg to convert to a .mp4 file will select to encode MPEG-4 video. I know this is confusing, but that's not what you want for HTML5 video.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments discussion, I think I have enough data to answer your question:

1. Originally, your problem video had a .flv extension. This was most likely a format that an HTML5-compatible browser could not handle (I say 'likely' because it very well could have been a correct file with an incorrect file extension; the file extension would have triggered the wrong MIME type to be sent via the web server response which can confuse some browsers).
2. Your quick, proof-of-concept video conversion is inadequate. `ffmpeg -i v1.mp4 v2.mp4` will generate a .mp4 file that has MPEG-4 part 2 video, which is not generally supported by HTML5-compatible browsers. You will need to make sure the video is in H.264 format.

So, in general, make sure your videos fall into the fairly rigid constraints defined by your delivery mechanism. In this case, HTML5 video tag requires MP4 files with H.264 video and AAC audio.

Comment: thanks for ur detailed explanation and helped a lot to know concept, and my point is how can we convert a video of flv format in to mp4 with H.264 video and AAC audio ?

Comment: yeah i had tried to convert with the below command mencoder /shiva/1100000.flv -ovc x264 -oac twolame -o /shiva/1100000.mp4 actually the video has been onverted but when i tried to display it in web page, still the same problem the video is not playing